# Extracting the concrete type argument from a type extending a generic type in java annotation processors

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Consider I have a type:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  boolean foo();
}
```

And I create BarFoo like so:

```
class BarFoo implements Foo<Bar> {
  boolean foo();
}
```

In a Java6 Annotation Processor, with access to the TypeElement BarFoo, how can I discover the concrete type with which this non-generic subclass was parameterized in the context of implementing Foo (specifically Bar).

And how, further, when I have a more complex hierarchy, like so:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  boolean foo();
}

class BarFoo implements Foo<Bar> {
  boolean foo();
}

class Grandchild extends BarFoo {}
```

How, given Grandchild's TypeElement could I find out the type of the type parameter of Foo?

Please note - I do not need to know the reflection APIs that will do this, but specifically the javax.lang.model and javax.annotation.processing APIs that will get me to `Bar` in this scenario.

Edit: I changed the return type from T to boolean, because in my real-world case, I don't have any method that returns T that might prove a workaround.  I need to get it from the type hierarchy, not from method return types, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

I would try:

- `TypeElement.getInterfaces()` -> `List<? extends TypeMirror>`
- `TypeMirror.accept(...)` visitor which checks for `DeclaredType`
- `DeclaredType.getTypeArguments()` -> `List<? extends TypeMirror>` which should give you a `TypeElement` for `Bar`

For the `Grandchild` probably the same scheme, but first `getSuperclass()`.

Another option is to go from `Foo`, check `getTypeParameters()` which would give you `T` and then look for a method which has `T` as `getReturnType()` and then look for the implementations of that method (probably not so easy if you consider the signature and not just name) and finally find out which return type has the implementation. But this is way more complex.

Comment: Yeah - this is the problem, I've overspecified my example.  Grandchild is what I need, but for arbitrary implementers of Foo<T> at any depth, with any amount of mucking in between.  But that's a good pattern, and  I think that's what I've got to go with.

Comment: Also - assume I don't have anything that returns T - the above example was malformed to accidentally provide that option.